# How does Python handle complicated calculations?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, arcpy

It might be a very simple problem but seems I am not able to see it.
I have a list of point ordered clockwise and want to calculate the centroid of these point (a convex polygon) using the following function according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon):

[image]
[image]

and

[image]

```
def calculateCentroid(raLinks,raNodes, links, nodes):  

orderedPointsOfLinks = orderClockwise(raLinks,raNodes, links, nodes)

arg1 = 0
arg2 = 0
Xc = 0
Yc = 0
i = 0
for point in orderedPointsOfLinks:
    arg1 += point.Y*(orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].X)
    arg2 += (orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].Y)*point.X
    Xc += (point.X+(orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].X))*(((orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].Y)*point.X)-(point.Y*(orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].X)))
    Yc += (point.Y+(orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].Y))*(((orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].Y)*point.X)-(point.Y*(orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].X)))    
    i+=1

area = (arg1-arg2)*0.5
print area

X = -Xc/(6*area)
Y = -Yc/(6*area)
print X , "   ", Y
```

calculating the area and the centorid using Arcpy shows that the calculated area by the above function is correct but the centroid is wrong.

what is the problem with Xc and Yc that I cant fix it?

If I change the for loop in the following way it works:

```
    for point in orderedPointsOfLinks:
        y0 = point.Y
        x0 = point.X
        x1 = orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].X
        y1 = orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].Y
        a = x0*y1 - x1*y0
        area += a
        Xc += (x0+x1)*a
        Yc += (y0+y1)*a
         i+=1
    area *= 0.5
    print area

    X = Xc/(6*area)
    Y = Yc/(6*area)
    print X , "   ", Y
```

here is a list of nodes to examine the code:

```
[(371623.876, 6159668.714),(371625.994, 6159661.094), (371624.319, 6159654.634), (371619.654, 6159649.86), (371614.194, 6159647.819), (371608.401, 6159648.449), (371601.544, 6159652.652), (371598.77, 6159658.058), (371599.318, 6159665.421), (371603.025, 6159671.805), (371611.372, 6159674.882 ), (371619.417, 6159673.065)]
```

Comment: Personally I'd find my code a *lot* easier to read if I appended a copy of the first point onto the end of the list of points, so I didn't have to retype (correctly) that wrap-around test every time I wanted to refer to the (i+1)th point. That's what Wikipedia did. Also, why not just iterate i on the length of the list (-1 if you append the first point to the end) and always index using i? I tried to decode your expressions from your code, but gave up.

Comment: @barny: you are right, I can do it in other ways, adding the first point at the end of the list or add it after the for-loop is over. But using the list comprehension makes it easier to understand the code (may not more efficient) as you do not need to as any extra step, just need to check if you are at the of the lis, consider the first one to close up the looop.

Comment: It's your code, but my $0.01 says that your code is practically illegible and illegible code is difficult to understand, debug and maintain. "simplifying" the for loop to iterate over the list of points makes you a) write code to initialise, use, and maintain a loop counter i, b) have to manually code wrapping round to the first node every time i+1 is needed - EIGHT times you have typed 'i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0', and c) mix your metaphors between point.X/Y and orderedPointsOfLinks[i+1 if i+1<len(orderedPointsOfLinks) else 0].X/Y. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

[source](https://github.com/pwcazenave/pml-git/blob/master/python/centroids.py)

Try:

```
import numpy

tp = [(371623.876, 6159668.714),(371625.994, 6159661.094), (371624.319, 6159654.634), (371619.654, 6159649.86),\
      (371614.194, 6159647.819), (371608.401, 6159648.449), (371601.544, 6159652.652), (371598.77, 6159658.058), \
      (371599.318, 6159665.421), (371603.025, 6159671.805), (371611.372, 6159674.882 ), (371619.417, 6159673.065),(371623.876, 6159668.714)]



# cx = sigma (x[i]+x[i+1])*((x[i]*y[i+1]) - (x[i+1]*y[i] ))
# cy = sigma (y[i]+y[i+1])*((x[i]*y[i+1]) - (x[i+1]*y[i] ))
cx = 0
cy = 0

p = numpy.array(tp)

x = p[:, 0]
y = p[:, 1]

a = x[:-1] * y[1:]
b = y[:-1] * x[1:]

cx = x[:-1] + x[1:]
cy = y[:-1] + y[1:]



tp = tp[:-1] #dont need repeat


def area():
    tox=0
    toy=0
    for i in range(len(tp)):
        if i+1 == len(tp):
            tox += tp[-1][0]*tp[0][1]
        else:
            tox += tp[i][0]*tp[i+1][1]

    for i in range(len(tp)):
        if i+1 == len(tp):
            toy += tp[-1][1]*tp[0][0]
        else:
            toy += tp[i][1]*tp[i+1][0]
    return abs(tox-toy)*0.5

ar = area()
Cx = abs(numpy.sum(cx * (a - b)) / (6. * ar))
Cy = abs(numpy.sum(cy * (a - b)) / (6. * ar))
print Cx,Cy
```

## Warning !

```
tp[0] == tp[-1]
```

So: first and last coordinates are same value...

Comment: I have no problem with the area. the problem is in calculating the coordinates as it returns wrong value while the area is correct. I suspect the way that python handles the complex equations is the problem, because every now and then the values for the coordinates change which is not reasonable if the points list is fix!!!!

Comment: @msc87 A place in Lithuania ?

Comment: It is a place in Sweden... anyway, thanks for the code, but the main question remains unanswered... why my first function is not working? while the second one is. this is more about understanding the problem as you may encounter in any other complex calculations just like this

Comment: Friend i get a lot of calculation  errors, I forget need same value first and last.  and create triangle form first coordinates. `cx = x[:-1] + x[1:]`  equal to duplicate `x` but first and last can't repeat, because already contained !